# pandas: assign a column values by slice with method chaining

Tags: pandas, method-chaining

In the following toy example, i'm trying to add a status column based on the outer merge results. The challenge is to preserve the chaining method as best described in [tom's blog](http://tomaugspurger.net/posts/method-chaining/). The commented out line is my attempt at it but it does not work

```
import pandas as pd

# Create sample data frames A and B
A = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

B = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    'value': [3, 4, 5, 6]
})

# Merge data frames A and B on the 'key' column and add an indicator column
merged = pd.merge(A, B, on='key', how='outer', indicator=True)

# add a status column
#{'both':'no change',
 #'left_only': 'added',
 #'right_only': 'removed'}

merged = (merged
          .assign (status = 'no change')
          #.assign(status = lambda x: x.loc[x._merge == 'left_only'], 'added')
          .drop('_merge', axis=1)
          )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should suffice - generally for the slice since you are assigning, you need to use a conditional (`map`, `np.where`, `np.select`, `pd.where` etc)

```
(A
.merge(B, on='key', how='outer', indicator=True)
.assign(status = lambda f: f._merge.map({"left_only":"added", 
                                          "both":"no change", 
                                          "right_only":"removed"}))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `DataFrame.apply` to get the status.

```
merged = (merged
          .assign(status = merged.apply(lambda x: 
                  'added' if x._merge == "left_only" else "", axis=1))
          .drop('_merge', axis=1)
          )
```

```
  key  value_x  value_y status                                                                
0   A      1.0      NaN  added                                                                
1   B      2.0      NaN  added                                                                
2   C      3.0      3.0                                                                       
3   D      4.0      4.0                                                                       
4   E      NaN      5.0                                                                       
5   F      NaN      6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it all in one-line using the 'walrus' operator, `:=`, `map` with a pre-defined dictionary, and changing the `indicator` column name in `merge` to a string:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create sample data frames A and B
A = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

B = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    'value': [3, 4, 5, 6]
})

d = {'both':'no_change',
     'left_only':'added',
     'right_only':'removed'}

merged = (merged_out:=pd.merge(A, B, on='key', how='outer', indicator='status'))\
            .assign(status=merged_out['status'].map(d))

merged
```

Output:

```
  key  value_x  value_y     status
0   A      1.0      NaN      added
1   B      2.0      NaN      added
2   C      3.0      3.0  no_change
3   D      4.0      4.0  no_change
4   E      NaN      5.0    removed
5   F      NaN      6.0    removed
```